# SQLite: How to get max from split string

Tags: sqlite

In a SQLite3 database, I have a table "*projects*" which *id* field is composed the following way:

```
[user id]_[user's project id]
```

For example, with **user id=45**, here is some data:

```
45_1
45_10
45_102
45_2
45_3
45_4
45_68
45_9
```

I need to **get the max of the project id**, which is the number after the '_' delimiter (which is *102* in the example). How can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT max(cast((substr(id, pos + 1) AS integer)) AS project_id
FROM (SELECT *, instr(id,'_') AS pos FROM projects);
```

Comment: or leave out `AS project_id`, doesn't really do much

Comment: Thank you Amir. A conversion from string to integer (`CAST(... AS INTEGER)`) is missing : `SELECT max(cast(substr(id, pos + 1) AS integer))
FROM (SELECT *, instr(id,'_') AS pos FROM projects);`. In the example given, you get "9" as max which is wrong and 102 with the conversion (with the cast function).

Answer (score -1):

`select max(cast(replace(id, "45_", "") as integer)) from projects;`

Now, I should point out this is not making very good use of SQL. Why not have two fields, so you could have proper foreign keys? It would make your life a lot easier

Second, if you don't only have project id = 45, you will need to use the CONCAT function. But I'm hoping you can figure that part out on your own with the functions above.

Comment: Not really a robust solution